# Add imageview to layout

Tags: android, imageview, android-relativelayout

I want to create image view from code and add to layout...But l don't use in-code setup layout.I have RelativeLayout in xml and use that `setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);`

How add imageview to layout?

Answer (score 7):

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.id_of_your_relative_layout_here);
ImageView iv = new ImageView(this)
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.some_drawable_of_yours); //or iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.some_drawable_of_yours));
rl.addView(iv);
```

Comment: I can't find id of layout?

Comment: @Filip what is your `RelativeLayout` id? You set it in XML like `<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/id_of_your_relative_layout_here"`

Comment: @Filip sorry, use rl.addView(iv);

Answer (score 0):

The XML should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:id="@+id/relativeblablabla"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

...........YOUR CODE HERE............

</RelativeLayout>
```

The code (inside the onCreate):

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeblablabla);
ImageView imageView = new ImageView (this);
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.YOUR_IMAGE);
rl.addView(imageView);
```