# Java - How to add a JPG/PNG file from resources(drawable) to a layout?

Tags: java, android

I have a relative layout:

```
 RelativeLayout battle_layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.battle);
```

I need to attach here a child (a JPG image from resources/drawable).

I was writting in c# and javascript earlier, but here it's a bit harder to accomplish :)

Is there someone who could help me? Thanks!

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18125050/add-imageview-to-layout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use one of these options. programmatically or in xml:

1. Add a ImageView to your layout
2. Set the image as background of your layout

Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/YOUR_IMAGE">

   <ImageView 
          android:src="@drawable/YOUR_IMAGE"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Code

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.YOUR_IMAGE);
battle_layout.addView(image);
```